# How do I generate non overlapping circles in a fixed region?

Tags: algorithm, graphics

What's the best way to generate a known number of non overlapping fixed radius circles in a limited space?

Comment: You should be more specific. Is the distribution of the circles an issue? Should most of the surface be covered? The easiest way would be to start at x=r, y=r for circles of radius r, and put them one next to  the other, row by row, until you have enough of them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this with the least leftover space is to put the centers of the circles on a hexagonal grid, like the pattern you'd get if you were making a pyramid of coins.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want as many circles in a small area as possible, use [hexagonal close packing](http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~bel23/HCP.html).

Answer (score 3):

See [Circle packing theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_theorem) on wikipedia

Answer (score 2):

You could split the screen as a grid, and draw a circle in each "square" :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your problem is well specified. Any constrains on the generation?

Here's a rejection algorithm for a random collection of non-overlapping circles of fixed radius:

1. Maintain a list of all circles
2. generate a candidate by

   1. generate a random center in the allowed region
   2. Test each existing circle in your list for a collision with the candidate, and reject if any collision is found. If all pass, add this candidate to your list.
3. Goto #1 until you're satisfied with the number generated

**Edit:** read the question more closely, the radius is specified...

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on the shape of the space and other restrictions on the nature of the circles, which you didn't specify.  For example, to generate N non-overlapping circles in a rectangle with height Y and length X, let the diameter of each circle be either X/10*N or Y/10*N, whichever is smaller, and let each center be spaced evenly on a horizontal line dividing the rectangle, spanning half its length.